# Use SELECT DISTINCT ON with OrmLite

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I tried writing this code to use `SELECT DISTINCT ON`:

```cs
            var q = Db.From<WatchedUrlScanResult>();
            q.Join<WatchedUrlRecord>()
                .Where<WatchedUrlRecord>(x => x.TargetDomainRecordId == request.TargetDomainId)
                .And(x => x.ScanDate < fromEnd)
                .OrderBy(x => x.WatchedUrlRecordId)
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.ScanDate);

            q.SelectExpression = q.SelectExpression.Replace("SELECT",
                    $"SELECT DISTINCT ON ({q.Column<WatchedUrlScanResult>(x => x.WatchedUrlRecordId)})");

            var fromSnapshot = Db.Select<WatchedUrlScanResult>(q);
```

In debugger it shows the value has set for `SelectExpression` but the actual SQL that runs is just `SELECT` without `DISTINCT ON`.

I tried:

```cs
q.Select(q.SelectExpression.Replace("SELECT",
                    $"SELECT DISTINCT ON ({q.Column<WatchedUrlScanResult>(x => x.WatchedUrlRecordId)})"));
```

But I get:

> Potential illegal fragment detected

Is it possible to do this without making full query a string? (using `{q.Column<Table>(x => x.ColumnName)}` in a full string query is fine but not very readable compared to fluent syntax)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to perform a SELECT DISTINCT query in OrmLite using its `SqlExpression<T>` you would use the SelectDistinct() API, e.g:

```
var results = Db.Select(q.SelectDistinct());
```

But as you're trying to perform your own custom SQL distinct Query you'll need to use the [Custom SQL APIs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#typed-sqlexpressions-with-custom-sql-apis), e.g:

```
var sql = q.ToSelectStatement().Replace(what,with);
var results = Db.SqlList<WatchedUrlScanResult>(sql);
```